# How to show Text in Label properly in RTL mode?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have set Right To Left mode for Form and i have Label in that form.

Label Text is : **Sample Text:**

When i changed to RTL mode, it displays like **":Sample Text"**. Is there any way to display the Label text as like normal mode even i changed the form to RTL mode?

**":"** should be displayed at the end of the text.

[image]

Comment: Set the label's `RightToLeft` property to `RightToLeft.No`.

Comment: I have checked with that property. Is that the only way?

Comment: Why do you want a different way?

Comment: **What's your goal?** You can set `RightToLeft` property of the label to `No`. But if you want to create a right to left UI, it's not a good idea. It's not a correct way to create right to left UI. If both the RightToLeftLayout and RightToLeft properties are true, mirroring will be turned on for the form, and control placement and text flow will be right-to-left.

Comment: Ok..I can understand... Since the location of the Label remained in same position if i changed to RTL as **No**. Thats why i want some other way. But now i can finalize that this is the only way to display the text in proper way.

Comment: What's the benefit of creating such right to left form? In a right to left form, labels should be placed at right side of text boxes. Also the text direction should be right to left.

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Control alignment switching between LTR and RTL languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626266/control-alignment-switching-between-ltr-and-rtl-languages) Image in the question shows the result of setting only `RightToLeft` to yes, but the answer shows the correct way.

Comment: Thanks for your kind information

Comment: @NeelakandanK Did you find the options of the linked post useful?