# How to switch WinForms Form to RTL without flip the Title Bar

Tags: c#, winforms

Something like override `wndproc`
I found this topic [Control alignment switching between LTR and RTL languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626266/control-alignment-switching-between-ltr-and-rtl-languages)
But it doesn't related to Form. Its for Panel.

How to make Title Bar in the right. not in the left when switch to RTL mode.
[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1neBA.png)

I try the following code in the Form from the topic above.

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{

    get
    {
        CreateParams CP;
        CP = base.CreateParams;
        if (this.RightToLeftLayout &&
            this.RightToLeft == System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes)
            CP.ExStyle = CP.ExStyle | WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL | WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT;
        return CP;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: I need to change direction of WinForms (Form object's title bar) to be at the right. in RTL Mode of the form.

Comment: You need to setup a Container Control (a Panel, in the example), and use it as the base container for all the Controls in the Form. Then you can change the `RightToLeftLayout` on the Container (not the Form), to apply that layout -- You could also setup the parent Form so it changes the properties of the Container when its own properties, related to RTL layout, are changed. But this only affects what you see at run-time, not design-time. To also affect the layout at design-time, you need to provide a custom Designer for the Form class

Comment: There's something maybe else that can done without set a Container Control. maybe override CreateParams inside Form1.cs. IDK

Comment: Nope. That's a functionality that's applied by the system, when you set the style of a window to include `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL`. Then the layout of the child Controls of that window is modified accordingly. The window manager draws the Caption, its content and the borders of a window. Hence you want to apply that layout to a window (a Container control) that is not the Top-Level window. If you don't want a Container, you have to replicate what the System does, and switch the position of Controls using your own code

Comment: But I don't see what the problem is. The use of nested containers is standard design procedure, kind of mandatory these days, since you need design the content to handle DPI scaling. Nested containers help a lot here. A UserControl is also a Container, and it handles Double-Buffering better that other Containers

Comment: @Jimi, if you have alternate solution to make Form RTL without change Title Bar tell me. I don't want to use Option 2 above. and insert all controls inside a Panel. Because sometimes I will use 3 panels in single form. so Option 1 is preferred but without change TItle Bar position.

Comment: I found that Option2 doesn't work with TabControl when inserted inside Panel container.

Answer (score 0):

WinProc is not needed. Just set the `RightToLeft` property on the panel. E.g:

```
Form f = new Form();
TableLayoutPanel panel1 = new TableLayoutPanel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
panel1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
panel1.Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "Button1" }, 0, 0);
f.Controls.Add(panel1);
Application.Run(f);
```

The button will appear on the right side. Note: this only works on Panels with LayoutEngines that obey the `RightToLeft` property.

Comment: It looks like the OP is asking about setting `RightToLeftLayout` without switching the position of the System Menu and Buttons (probably also the Text of the window's Caption). So, yes, you need to override `CreateParams` (not `WndProc`), both on the Container and the Form, and maybe also override the `RightToLeftLayout` property of the Form, so you can set the Container's custom property (which in turn affects the values set in the Container's `CreateParams` override). Without that, you just change the text alignment, not the overall layout (e.g., Labels are not switched to the opposite side)